# Can I change the related_name when I get the nested data in Django-Rest-Framework?

Tags: python, django

Such as I have two Model, the first is the second's `ForeignKey`.

**code:**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    firstDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    another = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class MySubModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    my_model = models.ForeignKey(to=MyModel, related_name="mysubs")
```

In the **MyModelSerializer** it should be:

```
class MyModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    mysubs = MySubModelSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = "__all__"
```

The **result** will be like bellow:

```
[
    {
        "firstDate":xxxx,
        "another":xxxx,
        "mysubs":[
            {
             "name":xxx,
            }
         ]
    }
]
```

I want to replace the key `mysubs` to `children`, is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `source` argument to specify field's source:

```
children = MySubModelSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='mysubs')
```